# Particles after time expressions like "三週間"

Tags: grammar, particles, syntax

I am a beginner in Japanese so I was trying to write some simple sentences to practice my vocabulary and grammar.

I wanted to write the sentence:

> My friend is in Japan for three weeks.

as:

> 私の友達が　三週間　日本に　います。

I am unsure if I should put any particle after 三週間 and whether this sentence is grammatically correct at all.

Comment: これは参考になります？　-> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/saying-youll-do-have-done-something-for-a-certain-amount-of-time

Answer (score 2):

[[間]{かん}](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%96%93) itself is functioning as a suffix indicating 'interval' or 'period of time'. In other words, '三週間' literally translates to '三週 (three weeks) + 間 (during or for)'. Therefore, you don't need any other particle or suffix after '三週間'.

One more important thing you should note is [Japanese normally doesn’t put spaces between words](http://www.japanesereview.com/things-that-make-japanese-hard/).

Answer (score -2):

You could insert:

```
   私の友達が三週間のあいだ日本にいます。

   私の友達は、三週間の間 日本にいます。
```

三週間の間 sounds redundant but it's correct.

Many people insert に making it "...週間の間に" but it's often incorrect (sloppy diction).

This first example (below) is ungrammatical / illogical -- or especially sloppy.

> 【衝撃】たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ！ 皆さん、普段の生活の中で意識して”水”を飲 ...  .......

```
      ( I suppose she got prettier and/or younger-looking. )
```

> 緊急警告！！一週間の間に「東京大地震」がくる可能性があります。

Comment: …の間に is not incorrect but different from …の間. The former means that something happens within the three weeks and the latter means something continues for three weeks.