# Misplaced(?) に in たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ！

Tags: grammar, particle-に, modification

Related: [Particles after time expressions like "三週間"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38529/particles-after-time-expressions-like-%e4%b8%89%e9%80%b1%e9%96%93)

> 【衝撃】 たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ！皆さん、普段の生活の中で意識して”水”を飲...

1. Can you explain what's wrong with the に in 「たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」?

and/or

2. Can you modify/rewrite it to make it better?

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with this Japanese sentence, although it sounds informal. The key difference is "*for* three weeks" (continuously) vs "*within/in/after* three weeks". To say the former you don't need any particle after 週間:

> - 3週間日本にいる be in Japan *for* three weeks
> - 3週間水を飲み続ける keep drinking water *for* three weeks
> - 3週間のあいだ水を飲み続ける keep drinking water *for* three weeks
>     (sounds a bit redundant, but it can be heard)

Compare:

> - 3週間のあいだに変化する change *within* three weeks
> - 3週間以内に変化する change *within* three weeks
> - 3週間で帰宅する return home *in* three weeks
> - 3週間後に改善する improve *after* three weeks

In this sentence, the focus is the *change* happened to this person *only within* four weeks, so saying たった4週間のあいだに is okay. Without the word 変化, [*]たった4週間の間に水を飲み続ける ("keep drinking water only within four weeks"?) doesn't really make sense.

I feel 「○週間の間【あいだ】に」 (=within ○ weeks) is not wrong but a bit redundant and clumsy. When you write formally, I would suggest you use ○週間以内に or ○週間で instead.

Answer (score 2):

※　「たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」　を変に思わない人がいるらしい。　不思議！　（でも、数日間考えたら、かなり分かった）

※(withカッコ)　 「たった4週間の間に （ 毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の ） 変化がヤバすぎ」

カッコの中を短くしていくと変なのに気が付くはず　：

> 「たった4週間の間に　（　毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の　）　変化がヤバすぎ」
>
> 「たった4週間の間に　（　水を飲み続けた女性の　）　変化がヤバすぎ」
>
> 「たった4週間の間に　（　水を飲んだ女性の　）　変化がヤバすぎ」
>
> 「たった4週間の間に　（　女性の　）　変化がヤバすぎ」

---

※　「たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」　を変に思わない人がいるらしいので、その理由を推理する。

（　↓　以下の文なら、おかしくない。）

> <sub>「たった4週間で現れた毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」</sub>
>
> <sub>「たった4週間で起きた毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」</sub>
>
> 「たった4週間の間に起きた毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」
>
> 「たった4週間の間に起こった毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ」

「たった4週間の間に （ 毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性に ） 現れた 変化がヤバすぎ」

> 「たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性に現れた変化がヤバすぎ」
>
> 「たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性に起きた変化がヤバすぎ」
>
> 「たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性に起こった変化がヤバすぎ」

（　↑　以上の文なら、おかしくない。）

※(withカッコ)　 「たった4週間の間に （ 毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の ） 変化がヤバすぎ」

※　を変に思わない人は、上のカッコの中を読んでる間に 「現れた／起きた／起こった」 を探しているのを忘れるか、脳内補充してるんだろう。

または、「変化」という表現の中に、暗黙の「変化した」（変化ナリ）を感じ取ってるとか？

Answer (score 1):

It's very tempting to put a NI after  [... 週間の間], but it changes the meaning.

> 【緊急】 一週間ダイエット！ 増えた体重を簡単に落とす方法 ｜ ダイエットで ...
>   そんな食べ過ぎで増えてしまった体重を落とすには「一週間ダイエット」が効果的！ 一週間の間にあることをすれば、簡単に体重を落とすことができるんですよ。 ということで今回は、一週間ダイエットで増えた体重を落とす方法をご紹介します。

```
          一週間の間に あることをすれば、簡単に体重を落とすことができるんですよ。
```

This is an (or another) example of redundant NI.

The sentence is not ungrammatical per se, but is incorrect == The writer means :

- 一週間の間あることをすれば、 ---  [ you have to do something continuously for 1 week, ]

and not :

- 一週間の間に あることをすれば、---  [ you (only) have to do something by the end of that 1 week, ]