# Is this grammar correct? (span of time)

Tags: grammar, meaning

一週間後に行く means : We arrive there in a week.
日本語は九ヶ月間勉強している means : I've been studying Japanese for 9 months.
ニ日間に休む means : absent for 2 days.

Comment: This thread might be of help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/saying-youll-do-have-done-something-for-a-certain-amount-of-time/33966#33966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>一週間後に行く means "we'll go there after a week".</s>

"We arrive there in a week" should be 一週間の内{うち}に / 一週間以内に / 一週間で 着く.

"I've been studying Japanese for 9 months" for 日本語は九ヶ月間勉強している is correct.

ニ日間に休む means "I'll take a break sometime within a certain two days".

"Absent for 2 days" should be 二日間 いない / 休む

Comment: Could you please explain how the meaning of the original sentence would change if 後 and/or に were removed?  That is, how would  一週間行く (if it's grammatical) differ in meaning from 一周間後に行く? Thanks.

Comment: 一週間行く means "to have a one-week trip" or rarely that you repeat going there for a week.

Comment: `一週間後に行く means "we'll go there after a week". "We arrive there in a week" should be 一週間の内に / 一週間以内に` -> でも辞書には「in 《通例現在から数えて》(今から)～後に、～たてば ... The bus leaves in five minutes. バスはあと5分で出発する (after five minutes は「５分経過した後に(しばらくして)」の意: after は通例過去のことについて用いられる 」(プログレッシブ)「in [未来形とともに、通例現在を始点とする未来の期間の終点を指して](今から)～の後に、～経って (⇔ago)《期間の終点以前(before the end of a period)を表すことも可》Let's leave there in an hour. 一時間後にそこを出よう。after an hour にすると、afterは現在以外の時点を始点とすることになるので、たとえばそこに着いた時を始点をして「着いてから１時間後に」という解釈が可能になる」(ジーニアス) とあるので、 in a week は必ずしも「一週間以内に」でなく「(今から)一週間後に」「一週間たったら」でもいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ゆえに「一週間で」の解釈を提示しました。たしかにこちらを真っ先にあげるべきでしたね。

Comment: ??? `一週間後に行く means "we'll go there after a week". "We arrive there in a week" should be 一週間の内うちに / 一週間以内に / 一週間で 着く.` を読む限り、「一週間後に行く does NOT mean "We arrive there in a week"」とおっしゃっているように思えるのですが・・・。両方の辞書に、"in~" の訳として「～後に」って、はっきり書いてありますよね・・「Let's leave there **in** an hour. 一時間**後に**そこを出よう。」という例文も載ってますし。。

Comment: たしかにそうですね、「一週間で」を上げてる時点で「一週間後に」も含むわけで…

Answer (score 0):

> 日本語は九ヶ月間勉強している means : I've been studying Japanese for 9 months.

it's good, but (probably) a more usual way is: 私は日本語を ......

> ニ日間に休む means : absent for 2 days.

Remove NI.  --  it's very tempting to put a NI there ... even native Jp people do it (exactly that) incorrectly many time over in Web pages.

2 examples of misplaced (incorrectly inserted NI) at: 
[Misplaced(?) に in たった4週間の間に毎日3Lの水を飲み続けた女性の変化がヤバすぎ！](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38590/misplaced-%e3%81%ab-in-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f4%e9%80%b1%e9%96%93%e3%81%ae%e9%96%93%e3%81%ab%e6%af%8e%e6%97%a53l%e3%81%ae%e6%b0%b4%e3%82%92%e9%a3%b2%e3%81%bf%e7%b6%9a%e3%81%91%e3%81%9f%e5%a5%b3%e6%80%a7%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%89%e5%8c%96%e3%81%8c%e3%83%a4%e3%83%90%e3%81%99%e3%81%8e)

---

What you can do instead of inserting a NI :

- ニ日間 休む --  (with hankaku-space) -- I do this, but it's not accepted practice.
- ニ日間、休む --  It's ok if you don't overdo it (put too many commas, or 、 TEN ).

Some variations are: 　　　(TEN (、) is optional in each example)

- ニ日間は、休む --  one meaning is [ at least that amount ]
- ニ日間も、休む --   one meaning is [  that amount is too much ]
- ニ日間しか、休まない --    the meaning is [  that amount/period is short ]