# Do 分 and 秒 take 間 if I am talking about duration?

Tags: word-choice

30秒かかった or 30秒間かかった ?

10分かかった or 10分間かかった?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/saying-youll-do-have-done-something-for-a-certain-amount-of-time/33966#33966

Answer (score 2):

if you are using "kakatta", a quick online search indicates that it is far more common NOT to use 間 with that expression. However, 30秒間 and 10分間 are used in sentences where someone is describing how long to do something for. "Look at this picture for 30 seconds." "I walked for 10 minutes."